# With React, what is the best way to pass a useState array back and forth between components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I had some help with a previous issue with my little project, but I have a new problem I can't seem to understand. My program takes an array of objects (call them cards), and displays an on-screen card for each element in the array. I have an edit button for each card, which should open the edit form for the chosen item, and pre-populate it with its current state - this all works.

I want to be able to edit the item, save it back in place into the array, and have that 'card' updated. This is the main component:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactFitText from "react-fittext";
import Editform from "./Editform";

function Displaycards({ lastid }) {
  // dummy data hardcoded for now
  const [cards, setCards] = React.useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      gamename: "El Dorado",
      maxplayers: 4,
      freespaces: 1,
      tablenum: 5,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      gamename: "Ticket to Ride",
      maxplayers: 4,
      freespaces: 2,
      tablenum: 3,
    },
  ]);

  const [showForm, setShowForm] = React.useState(false);
  const [currentid, setCurrentid] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="cardwrapper">
      {cards.map(({ id, gamename, maxplayers, freespaces, tablenum }) => {
        return (
          <div key={id}>
            <div>
              <div className="card">
                <ReactFitText compressor={0.8}>
                  <div className="gamename">{gamename}</div>
                </ReactFitText>
                <div className="details">
                  <p>Setup for: </p>
                  <p className="bignumbers">{maxplayers}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="details">
                  <p>Spaces free:</p>
                  <p className="bignumbers">{freespaces}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="details">
                  <p>Table #</p>
                  <p className="bignumbers">{tablenum}</p>
                </div>
                <button type="button" className="playbutton">
                  I want to play
                </button>
                <br />
              </div>

              <div className="editbuttons">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="editbutton"
                  onClick={() => {
                    setShowForm(!showForm);
                    setCurrentid(id);
                  }}
                >
                  Edit
                </button>
                <button type="button" className="delbutton">
                  X
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      {showForm && (
        <div>
          <Editform cards={cards} setCards={setCards} id={currentid} />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Displaycards;
```

and this is the Editform.js which it calls at the bottom. As far as I can tell I'm passing my array, setter function, and id of the card I want to edit:

```
function Editform({ cards, setCards, id }) {
  const thisCard = cards.filter((card) => card.id === id)[0];
  const editThisCard = thisCard.id === id; // trying to match id of passed card to correct card in 'cards' array.
  console.log(editThisCard);

  function saveChanges(cardtochange) {
    setCards(
      cards.map(
        (
          card // intention is map back over the original array, and if the id matches that
        ) =>
          card.id === id // of the edited card, write the changed card back in at its ID
            ? {
                id: id,
                gamename: cardtochange.gamename,
                maxplayers: cardtochange.maxplayers,
                freespaces: cardtochange.freespaces,
                tablenum: cardtochange.tablenum,
              }
            : card // ... or just write the original back in place.
      )
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      {editThisCard && ( // should only render if editThisCard is true.
        <div className="form">
          <p>Name of game:</p>
          <input type="text" value={thisCard.gamename}></input>

          <p>Max players: </p>
          <input type="text" value={thisCard.maxplayers}></input>
          <p>Free spaces: </p>
          <input type="text" value={thisCard.freespaces}></input>

          <p>Table #: </p>
          <input type="text" value={thisCard.tablenum}></input>
          <p></p>
          <button
            type="button"
            className="playbutton"
            onClick={saveChanges(thisCard)} //remove to see edit form - leave in for perpetual loop.
          >
            Save changes
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Editform;
```

If I comment out the onClick for the button, the page renders. If it's in there, the page gets stuck in an infinite loop that even React doesn't catch.

The way I'm trying to recreate my array is based on advice I've read here, when searching, which said to take the original array, rebuild it item-for-item unless the ID matched the one I want to change, and to then write the new version in.

I suspect there might be a way to do it with my setter function (setCards), and I know there's an onChange available in React, but I don't know a) how to get it to work, or b) how - or even if I need to - pass the changed array back to the calling component.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is invoked directly upon components render:

> {saveChanges(thisCard)}

Rename it to a callback style signature:

> {() => saveChanges(thisCard)}

Also do add a jsfiddle/ runnable snippet for answerers to test ✌️.

Edit:

About the array of objects passing and updates, at your part the code is good where filter is used. We can apply idea of moving update logic to parent where data is located.

Now id + updated attributes could be passed to the update callback in child.

To give you [hint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), can use spread operator syntax to update items out of existing objects.

Comment: This is probably just my lack of JS knowledge then. Why is it invoked on render, when it's only there as the onClick action for the button?

Comment: The onClick expects a callable type. However the syntax means invoking function (inline).

Comment: Thanks, combined with changing the input fields to have defaultValue instead of value means I can edit it. I'm still stuck with the principle of creating the new version of the array, and passing it back to the calling function, replacing the existing one.

Comment: This should probably be split into two separate questions.